# GO term for orthologous gene IDs

Tags: gene

I have a list of orthologous gene IDs from the first supplementary file in [here](http://genome.cshlp.org/content/suppl/2014/05/21/gr.159384.113.DC1.html).

The gene IDs are of the following type:

```
EOG6STSR2
EOG60ZRJB
EOG6SBFJ2
EOG6P5KX3
EOG6B5PRW
```

I want to do the *GO term* analysis for these IDs. I tried mapping them to FlyBase IDs from *OrthoDB* and then using [DAVID](https://david.ncifcrf.gov/tools.jsp). But many of the orthologous IDs are not getting mapped to the FlyBase ones so I'm not getting proper results.

Is it possible to get the GO term analysis done directly for the orthologous gene IDs without mapping them to the FlyBase IDs?

Comment: You mean the `.bed` files in the study?

Comment: Yes. I got the orthologous gene IDs from the fourth column of the bed file.

Comment: I have a solution for accurate ID conversion but it makes use of a small script (that you'll have to write). The idea is quite simple and the implementation is easy. Would that be fine or you just want an existing reliable ID converter?

Comment: I'm comfortable with writing a script. I had written one initially which took the file from OrthoDB, extracted the lines with _DMEL_ as Organism ad then mapped the IDs in the given file.